# Ошибка: Parameter value [%NEW%] did not match expected type

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, rest

Возвращает ошибку: Parameter value [%NEW%] did not match expected type

запрос: http://localhost:8080/api/users?status=NEW

В приложении скрин локальной базы. Читал много решений как это можно исправить, но не удалось решить проблему с типами.

Хочу использовать enum для того чтобы сохранять значение конкретных статусов в БД, затем когда реализовал роут с фильтрацией по статусу получил ошибку типов.

Пробывал разные рекомендуемые версии Hibernate - тщетно. У кого есть опыт в работе с enum подскажите что упустил?

UserController

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/users")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:63342")   
                            
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    public UserController(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity createUser (@RequestBody Users user) {
        userService.addUser(user);
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Пользователь успешно создан");
    }

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity getAll() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(userService.getAll());
    }

    // фильтр по статусу
    @GetMapping(params = "status")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Users>> getUsersStatus(@RequestParam("status") String status) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(userService.getUsersByStatus(status));
    }


    //фильтр по компании
    @GetMapping(params = "companyName")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Users>> getUsersCompanyName(@RequestParam("companyName") String company) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(userService.getUsersByCompanyName(company));
    }


}
```

Entity

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class Users {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name="surname")
    private String surname;

    @Column(name="company_name")
    private String companyName;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name="post")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private UserPost post;

    public UserPost getPost() {
        return post;
    }

    public void setPost(UserPost post) {
        this.post = post;
    }

    @Column(name="department")
    private String department;

    @Column(name="status")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private UserStatus status;

    public UserStatus getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(UserStatus status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
}
```

repositoty

```
public interface UserRepo extends CrudRepository <Users, Long> {

    // фильтрация по статусу

    Users findByStatus(String status);
    List<Users> findUsersByStatusContaining(String usersUserStatus);

    // фильтрация по компании

    Users findByCompanyName(String company);
    List<Users> findUsersByCompanyNameContaining(String userCompanyName);
}
```

Service

```
@Service
public class UserService {


    @Autowired
    private UserRepo userRepo;

    public UserService(UserRepo userRepo) {
        this.userRepo = userRepo;
    }

    // логика создания пользователя

    public Users addUser(Users user) {
        userRepo.save(user);
        return user;
    }


    // логика получения списка пользователей

    public Iterable <Users> getAll() {
        return userRepo.findAll();
    }

    // поисковый запрос, фильтр по полю status

    public List<Users> getUsersByStatus(String status) {
        return userRepo.findUsersByStatusContaining(status);
    }

    // фильтр по компании
    public List<Users> getUsersByCompanyName(String company) {
        return userRepo.findUsersByCompanyNameContaining(company);
    }
}
```

enum

```
public enum UserStatus {
    ACTIVE,
    NEW,
    REQUEST,
    BLOCKED
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

полный текст ошибки
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Parameter value [%NEW%] did not match expected type [com.example.books_shope.enums.UserStatus (n/a)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [%NEW%] did not match expected type [com.example.books_shope.enums.UserStatus (n/a)]] with root cause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

findUsersByStatusContaining - дословно "Найти пользователей по полю статус, в котором содержится текст...". То есть строка "NEW" в запросе будет выглядеть, как "%NEW%". Hibernate будет пытаться привести строку "%NEW%" к enum, у него ничего не получится и вывалится ошибка.
Можно попробовать findUsersByStatusContaining заменить на findUsersByStatus, тогда не будут добавлены знаки процента.

Но вообще, я бы сделал немного по другому. Мы уже знаем все состояния, которые могут прилететь в параметре "status" - они ограничены enum UserStatus. Можно было бы сделать так

```
// фильтр по статусу
@GetMapping(params = "status")
public ResponseEntity<List<Users>> getUsersStatus(@RequestParam("status") UserStatus status) {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(userService.getUsersByStatus(status));
}
```

и в дополнении к этому у класса UserService

```
public List<Users> getUsersByStatus(UserStatus status) {
    return userRepo.findUsersByStatus(status);
}
```

и у репозитория

```
List<Users> findUsersByStatus(UserStatus status);
```

Comment: Благодарю за помощь, удалось запустить и фильтровать по полю status, если я правильно понял, то это одна из особенностей hibernate, которую следует учитывать при работе с Enum.